# Задача по программированию на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Учусь сейчас на курсе программирования на Python. Немножко не понял домашнее задание которое нам дали:

Попросите пользователя ввести число с клавиатуры. Если число делится на 3 без остатка, выведите сообщение "Число делится на 3". Если число больше 10, выведите сообщение "Число больше 10". Если число не удовлетворяет ни одному из условий, выведите сообщение "Число не соответствует условиям".

Я вроде бы и решил, но есть сомнения что это неправильно, буду рад если вы проверите и если будут ошибки - исправите. Я решил пойти по пути наименьшего сопротивления, путём просто проверки чисел которые написаны в input. Но по хорошему, это нужно сделать через реальную проверку на деление чисел, причём через целочисленное деление. Пожалуйста помогите и исправьте если сможете, ниже прикрепляю код:

```
a = int(input("Введите число: "))

if a == 3 or a == 6 or a == 9:
    print("Число делится на три.")
elif a > 10:
    print("Число больше десяти.")
else:
    print("Число не соответствует условиям.")
```

Comment: что ожидается при числе, например, `12` - оно и на 3 делится нацело и больше 10. Потому что в условии задачи не сказано про прекращении обработки после первого "успеха"

Comment: да норм все работает, как можно сомневаться в такой простой проге

Comment: @n1tr0xs Понятно. А как сделать саму проверку на делимость? Потому что в этом коде всё ограничивается лишь проверкой написанных пользователем чисел, т.е. если написал 3, 6, или 9 - получится что число делится на три, а остальные если писать, то будет писать что либо число не соответствует условиям, либо просто число больше десяти

Comment: вот так`a%3 == 0`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Не нужно делать заголовки "задача по программированию". Здесь 99,95% вопросов - задача по программированию. Заголовок должен кратко отражать **конкретную** проблему, о которой речь. [ask]

Comment: @Эникейщик извините, буду теперь знать!

Answer (score 0):

Вам следует заменить первую проверку на проверку с использованием `%`(остаток от деления)

```
# ...code above...
if (a % 3 == 0):
    print('Число делится на три')
# ...code below...
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, буду знать теперь как это делать, я в принципе всё понял, просто сидел мучался, не мог понять как эту проверку делать.

Answer (score 0):

```
InPut = int(input("Введите число >>> ")) # Получаем число
if InPut % 3 == 0 and InPut > 10: # Если число делится на три и больше десяти, то...
    print("Число делится на 3 и больше 10")
elif InPut % 3 == 0: # Если число делится на три, то...
    print("Число делится на 3")
elif InPut > 10: # Если число больше десяти, то...
    print("Число больше 10")
else: # Если число не прошло условия выше, то...
    print("Число не соответствует условиям")
```